# Target first child after css class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an overview of `item`s, which are built up like this:

```
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
```

I want to target the first `item`-class and every `item`-class every time a `lastinrow`-class has passed. Is this possible? Or should I just use `:nth-child(#)`?

If using `:nth-child` is the solution, what number(s) should I use instead of the # if I want to target the first one and every 4th one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This selects all `.item` elements that are either the first child or immediately follow a `.lastinrow` item:

```
.item:first-child,
.lastinrow + .item {
}
```

For the sake of completeness, if you want to select every `.item` element which is the 3rd child starting from 1 you would write:

```
.item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
}
```

```css
.item:first-child,
.lastinrow + .item {
    background: #FC0;
}
.item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">First item</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
<div class="item">Item following last-in-row</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) to select the next element. You can then combine this with `:first-child` to select the first `.item` element.

```css
.lastinrow + .item,
.item:first-child {
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
```

If you want to target every 3rd element (your question says 4th, but I guess you mean 3rd...), you can use `3n + 1` in your `nth-child` selector:

```css
.item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item lastinrow">...</div>
```

If you *do* actually want to select every 4th element, you'd use `4n + 1` instead.